# Combine rows of SQL Union query

Tags: sql

I am trying to perform a SQL query which generates a table with two columns referencing the same data but using different conditionals.  My result query needs to contain columns like:

Query Result:

- Total Quantity
- Available Quantity

Where *Total Quantity* is the total number of a certain item and *Available* is a subset of the same item, but only those which are flagged as "Available".

I've attempted to use a UNION of the form:

```
SELECT
   '0' as Quantity,
   COUNT (item.pkid) as Available
FROM itemInstance, itemType
WHERE
   itemInstance.availability = 'AVAILABLE'
   AND itemInstance.type = itemType.primary_key
UNION
SELECT
   COUNT (DISTINCT item.pkid) as Quantity,
   '0' as Available
FROM itemInstance, itemType
WHERE itemInstance.type = itemType.primary_key
```

Which of course produces something like:

```
  Quantity  Available
1    0          2
2    4          0
3    0          3
4    7          0
```

When I really want:

```
  Quantity  Available
1    4          2
2    7          3
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think I understand all aspects of your query, but it should basically work like this:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) as Quantity,
   SUM(CASE WHEN itemInstance.availability = 'AVAILABLE'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) As Available
FROM itemInstance, itemType
WHERE itemInstance.type = itemType.primary_key
```

The `CASE` will be `1` for each matchin row and `0` for not-matchin rows, so the sum of those values is the count of available items.

BTW: You might want to switch to explicit join notation for better readablity (especially with more complex queries):

```
...
FROM itemInstance
JOIN itemType ON ( itemInstance.type = itemType.primary_key )
```

Comment: Good on you asking him to use explicit joins. Implicit joins are such a poor practice.